# Como faço para dividir em Assembly?

Tags: assembly

Boas Pessoal ,

Sou novo em assembly, estou com problemas à fazer divisão. 
Quando compilo o programa na linha de comandos, aparece me este erro **Floating point exception**.

```
.section .data

.global op1
.global op2
.global resultado

.section .text

.global Conta
```

Conta:

---

## prologue

```
pushl %ebp    
movl %esp, %ebp   

movl op1, %edx
movl op2, %eax
divl %edx, %eax
movl %eax, resultado
```

## epilogue

```
movl %ebp, %esp  
popl %ebp   

ret
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A instrução [`div`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/DIV.html), divide o valor (inteiro sem sinal) armazenado no par de registradores `edx:eax` (dividendo - 64 bits) pelo operador de destino (pode ser um registrador ou posição de memória - 32 bits), e armazena o quociente em `eax` e o resto em `edx`.

Como você está armazenando o valor de `op1` em `edx`, e dividindo `edx:eax` por `edx` (que faz parte do dividendo), provavelmente o resultado da divisão é maior que 32 bits e isso gera o erro **Floating point exception** (ou *divide error*, conforme o [manual da Intel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)).

Uma solução possível para o problema é zerar o registrador `edx` e utilizar um registrador diferente de `edx` e `eax` para armazenar o divisor (caso a divisão que você está tentando fazer seja de 32 bits mesmo e não 64).

---

Segue um exemplo do seu código alterado, utilizando o registrador `ebx` para armazenar o divisor:

```
Conta:
        push %ebp
        movl %esp, %ebp
        movl op2, %ebx       # armazena o divisor em ebx
        xorl %edx, %edx      # zera edx (parte alta do dividendo)
        movl op1, %eax       # armazena o dividendo (parte baixa) em eax
        divl %ebx, %eax      # divide edx:eax por ebx
        movl %eax, resultado
        movl %ebp, %esp
        pop %ebp
        ret
```

---

Exemplo de execução: divisão de 13 por 3:

```
Conta () at teste.a:30
30              movl op2, %ebx
(gdb)
31              xorl %edx, %edx
(gdb)
32              movl op1, %eax
(gdb)
33              divl %ebx, %eax
(gdb) info registers
eax            0xd      13      <----- parte "baixa" do dividendo
ecx            0x0      0
edx            0x0      0       <----- parte "alta" do dividendo
ebx            0x3      3       <----- divisor
...
(gdb) s
34              movl %eax, resultado
(gdb) info registers
eax            0x4      4       <----- quociente
ecx            0x0      0
edx            0x1      1       <----- resto
ebx            0x3      3
...
```